# My scrollView does not scroll?

Tags: android

I have a main layout that fits the screen, then i want it to scroll down to show the button, 
i tried removing fillviewport but it then collapses the view, 
I even made the linear layout wrap_content and it does the same, collapses the view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/inner_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/detail_note_date_text"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/detail_title_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
                android:hint="@string/title_hint"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/detail_note_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="48"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/note_hint"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/reminder_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_no_set_reminder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/radio_button_no_set_reminder"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_set_reminder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/radio_button_set_reminder"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_note_date_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    tools:text="@string/demo_date"/>
```

Comment: how does it look when you run the app ? Can you send its screenshot here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/inner_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/detail_note_date_text"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/detail_title_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:hint="@string/title_hint"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/detail_note_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/note_hint"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/reminder_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_no_set_reminder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_button_no_set_reminder"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_set_reminder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_button_set_reminder"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/detail_note_date_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/demo_date"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've just edited your code.Please try to learn first layout design properly and view will scroll only if it your contents are big enough to go out of screen.

Comment: It works that way, but I want the editText field to take up the screen ? Is there any way you could assist me with that ?

Comment: Means you want to scroll whole layout above when the keyboard for edittext opens right?

Comment: I want the 2nd edit text to be big, that is the reason i gave it a weight, with height wrap_content, it shrinks down, any solution to keep it big and still have scrolling ?

Comment: If you write something in it, it will automatically increase its height.